# What are some new emerging programming languages

Tags: programming-languages, new-operator

What are some new and exciting programming languages?

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: What do you mean, exactly?  Some languages have been around for a while, but are just now getting noticed.

Comment: Definitely for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, though might get closed as being far too open.

Answer (score 2):

**C++0x**

(This is an extension to C++, however amount of additions are huge.)

Comment: It's actually C++1x now... >_>

Comment: @muntoo, correct and mostly it will be C++11, as it's expected to be released this year.

Comment: Actually, it would be more exciting to have **C++. 2012. *Now in theatres.***

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript

JavaScript is continuously evolving. The Chromium team is working to help with WebGL development.

Answer (score 0):

This might not fit the question criteria, but the [D language](http://digitalmars.com/d/) is quite nice.  Unfortunately, support for it is somewhat lacking and I've never seen it used in the "real world."

Comment: "support for it is somewhat lacking and I've never seen it used in the "real world."" - sounds really useful.....

Comment: @Mitch You could call it "emerging."

Comment: or possibly "currently useless" !

Comment: @Mitch Sure, if you'd like.  The question didn't ask for the most practical languages.